# Iterating calculation over 15 groups

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, iterated-function

I'm working on some QA/QC for some of my data, and am interested in looking at the percentage of my data in each group that has been flagged as potentially more prone to error. I have 15 groups that I want to iterate this over, but I'm not sure how best to do this. Maybe a for loop?

```
# pulling out group 1 data
group_1 <- filter(flow_group_df, GROUP == 1) 

#looking at number of flagged occurrences in group 1
group_1_flagged <- length(which(group_1 == "flagged")) 

#total number of checked occurrences that havent been flagged
class_1_checked <- length(which(group_1 == "checked"))
```

Comment: Just do a group by operation `flow_group_df %>% group_by(GROUP, group_1) %>% summarise(n = n())`  If there are more groups in `group_1`, do a `filter` `flow_group_df %>% filter(group_1 %in% c('flagged', 'checked')) %>% group_by(GROUP, group_1) %>% summarise(n = n())`  or just `table(df[c("GROUP", "group_1")]`

Answer (score 0):

Consider R's built-in `stats` library with full aggregation using `aggregate`:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(num_col ~ GROUP + group_1, flow_group_df, length)
```

Or inline aggregation using `ave`:

```
flow_group_df$group_1_count <- with(flow_group_df, ave(num_col, GROUP, group_1, FUN=length))
```

---

To demonstrate with random data:

```
set.seed(72318)
flow_group_df <- data.frame(GROUP = c("julia", "r", "pandas"),
                            group_1 = sample(c("flagged", "checked"), 60, replace=TRUE),
                            num_col = runif(60, 0, 100))
```

**Aggregate**

```
agg_df <- aggregate(num_col ~ GROUP + group_1, flow_group_df, length)    
agg_df <- with(agg_df, agg_df[order(GROUP, group_1),])                      # ORDER BY GROUPS
row.names(agg_df) <- NULL                                                   # RESET ROW NAMES
colnames(agg_df)[3] <- "count"                                              # RENAME KEY COL

agg_df         
#    GROUP group_1   count
# 1  julia checked      10
# 2  julia flagged      10
# 3 pandas checked       8
# 4 pandas flagged      12
# 5      r checked       7
# 6      r flagged      13
```

**Ave** *(count and percent calculations)*

```
flow_group_df$group_1_count <- with(flow_group_df, ave(num_col, GROUP, group_1, FUN=length))
flow_group_df$group_1_pct <- with(flow_group_df, ave(num_col, GROUP, group_1, FUN=length)) /
                                  with(flow_group_df, ave(num_col, GROUP, FUN=length))

flow_group_df <- with(flow_group_df, flow_group_df[order(GROUP, group_1),])    # ORDER BY GROUPS
row.names(flow_group_df) <- NULL                                               # RESET ROW NAMES

tail(flow_group_df, 20)
#    GROUP group_1   num_col group_1_count group_1_pct
# 41     r checked  8.128056             7        0.35
# 42     r checked 86.439911             7        0.35
# 43     r checked 75.488474             7        0.35
# 44     r checked 88.120510             7        0.35
# 45     r checked 43.058268             7        0.35
# 46     r checked 46.662674             7        0.35
# 47     r checked 42.329505             7        0.35
# 48     r flagged 94.959380            13        0.65
# 49     r flagged 64.817015            13        0.65
# 50     r flagged 61.118952            13        0.65
# 51     r flagged 69.104977            13        0.65
# 52     r flagged 98.078729            13        0.65
# 53     r flagged 74.857959            13        0.65
# 54     r flagged 83.813440            13        0.65
# 55     r flagged 99.069011            13        0.65
# 56     r flagged 62.298414            13        0.65
# 57     r flagged 14.335920            13        0.65
# 58     r flagged 70.404048            13        0.65
# 59     r flagged 18.744892            13        0.65
# 60     r flagged 21.598072            13        0.65
```